# Tango accurate measurements

Tags: point-cloud-library, google-project-tango

I am using different apps on the Google Tango and uses the java point cloud library application with my own ICP algorithm to build an point cloud of my room. I did then some deeper research and come to conclusion that the average error would is around the 3%. I understand that the distance error would increase, but this is also 3% linear.

I have two hypothesis for this results,

1) Google cannot guarantee that the measurements are accurate, so adding an error would people slow down just to trust the measurements.

2) Bad calibration

**edit**
I found something strange about the depthmap could this have something to do with the scaling?

[image]

Comment: Hi Martjin, I didn't get your question about "so adding an error would people slow down just to trust the measurements." In general, I think 3% sounds like a proper benchmark, especially with 1% of motion tracking drift, that could lead to the total error to 3%. What kind of accuracy you are looking for?

Comment: @JasonGuo I want a precision of 1 cm max on a room of 6mx6m

Comment: I don't think it can guarantee that precision but it is definitely possible. Also, I just remembered one thing to check. On the device, there's a 13 degree rotation on the sensor bar, so let's say if you are testing depth by facing it against a flat wall 1 meter away, and the device's screen is parallel to the wall, the depth camera will be face 13 degree up rather than facing forward. So you might want to take this into your consideration, all these sensor extrinsic can be queried from the API using TangoService_getPoseAtTime function.